# How to recursively display nested data in tree structure format in html when depth is unknown

Tags: angular

```
[{
    "College1": [
        [
            "Studname1"
        ],
        [
            "Studname2"
        ]
    ],
    "College2": [{
            "Stud1": [{
                "Stud2.1": [
                    "Value"
                ]
            }]
        },
        [
            "Statement1",
            "Statements2"
        ]
    ]
}]
```

I have above json data ,how can I display the above data recursively using ngTemplate. Please let me know is there any other way to display the data except ngTemplate

Comment: `{{ jsondata | json }}` isn't this enough?

Comment: please explain the complete code. Not understood from your comment

Comment: you can see the below code from Tony. Angular provides a pipe called `json` that can display a json object.

Answer (score 0):

html.component.ts

```
data = [{
"College1": [
    [
        "Studname1"
    ],
    [
        "Studname2"
    ]
],
"College2": [{
        "Stud1": [{
            "Stud2.1": [
                "Value"
            ]
        }]
    },
    [
        "Statement1",
        "Statements2"
    ]
]
}]
```

html.component.html

```
<pre>{{data| json}}</pre>
```

Comment: on UI I can't display the whole data at a time na...Need to check parent key then its inner key and again inner keys...how can i display such type of data

Comment: is it something like a tree structure? on parent key click expand inner object??

Comment: Yes on parent key click ,inner object should be display

Comment: have you tried codemirror ?? https://codemirror.net/

Comment: There I am not getting anything related to this